# Filter django queryset by its related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF QuesionSet  View inherited from generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

I also have 2 models (simplified):

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_set = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSet, related_name="questions")
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...other_fields

class QuestionSet(models.Model):

    ...fields
```

Now I need to return a question_set object in the view, that only has questions that are True. Something like this:

```
"id": 1,
"questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "isArchived": true
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "isArchived": true
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "isArchived": true
        },
]
```

I am trying to override get_object() method in the view to return these values. So how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be trickier than I thought. I suggest to use a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```py
#content of serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Question, QuestionSet


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'is_archived', 'question_set']


class QuestionSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    inactive_questions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionSet
        fields = ['id', 'inactive_questions']

    def get_inactive_questions(self, obj):
        active_questions = obj.questions.filter(is_archived=True)
        return QuestionSerializer(active_questions, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

More details can be find in the [Github repo](https://github.com/michaelhaar/Filter-django-queryset-by-its-related-field)

Comment: this solution will require more DB queries, I solved it in the get_queryset()

Answer (score 1):

First, you can overwrite the `get_queryset` method to filter the queryset:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    return QuestionSet.objects.select_related('questions').filter(is_archived=True)
```

Next you have to modify the serializer class in order to get the required output format. Try using [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships):

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'is_archived']

class QuestionSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QuestionSet
        fields = ['id']
```

Comment: select_related probably won't work here as questions is not a field of QuestionSet

Comment: maybe you can use: `QuestionSet.objects.filter(question__is_archived=True)`. See section [Querying in the opposite direction]( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: no, that won't work either as it returns a queryset of all the  Questions, even if you add the QuestionSet id in the filter. I need to filter out nested field, not QuestionSet

Comment: I'll try to provide you a demo project

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by overriding qs:

```
return self.queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('questions', 
                               queryset=Question.objects.filter(is_archived=True)))
```