# DRF - How to queryset to only objects that the user is the owner of within an intermediate model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm my DRF API, I have an intermediate model `Ingredient` that links two models, `Product` and `Recipe`.

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
```

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ingredient')
```

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   quantity = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

In my current DRF `generics.CreateAPIView` for `Ingredient`, I want it to only display and allow a user to see and send a post request to create a new `Ingredient` entry for a `Recipe` that they own. But right now it keeps displaying Recipes for all users.

I tried filtering the `Recipe` for the `Ingredient` model in my `serializers.py` with:

```
serializers.py:

class IngredientPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   recipes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   def get_recipes(self, obj):
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        return recipes
   class Meta:
      model = Ingredient
      fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Looks like what you need is a custom permission class: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following function to the view that uses the `IngredientPostSerializer`

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    current_user = self.request.user
    return self.queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('recipe', 
                               queryset=Recipe.objects.filter(user=current_user)))
```

please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152407/filter-django-queryset-by-its-related-field) for more details